# Desconocimiento de como funciona un TimePickerDialog en Android Studio con Java

Tags: java, android-studio

Llevo unos días detrás de éste tema y no logro dar con la solución

Lo intenté primero con una clase y también con distintos métodos, pero no acabo de entender como funciona

Mi intención es pedir al usuario que indique el tiempo para comenzar la cuenta atrás

Deseo usar un TimePickerDialog, pero éste que uso en concreto, sólo me pide horas y minutos, que por cierto, las horas no me deja poner 0, y no me deja poner segundos, sólo minutos. Bueno, o no se como se pondrían.

Yo desearía poder seleccionar las horas, los minutos y los segundos.

Recoger los tres datos en tres variables y enviarlas a un TextView

Método del TimePickerDialog:

```
private void metodoSolicitarTiempo(){
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(PaginaTemporizador.this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {
                    //horas es el textview donde deseo ver el dato que retorna
                    //ésto funciona, pero aunque ponga 0 horas, siempre aparece 1
                    //también desearía ver los segundos
                    Horas.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                }
            }, horas, minutos, false); //ésta parte no la entiendo. Las variables horas y minutos son de tipo int, pero no entiendo porque las hay que colocar y para qué
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Éste es el método que pone en funcionamiento el Temporizador:

```
public void IniciarCuenta(){

    //Esta parte la utilizaba antes con otro método que pedía horas, minutos y segundos de forma manual por medio de Edittext, ahora no lo utilizo
    //segundos = (Integer.parseInt(Segundos.getText().toString()) + (Integer.parseInt(Minutos.getText().toString()) * 60) + ((Integer.parseInt(Horas.getText().toString()) * 60) * 60));

    //Lo que trataría de hacer, sería pasar a segundos las tres variales retornadas por el método anterior

    new CountDownTimer(segundos * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            segundos = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            //Con éstos cálculos mezclo un poco métodos que fui utilizando
            //si ahora me llegaran las variables con cada dato de forma individual, algunos de éstos cálculos estaría de más
            int horas = segundos / (60 * 60);
            int tempMint = (segundos - (horas * 60 * 60));
            int minutos = tempMint / 60;
            segundos = tempMint - (minutos * 60);
            int tempSeg = ((segundos - (horas * 60 * 60))) - (tempMint - (minutos * 60)) - segundos;
            miliSegundos = tempSeg / 60;

            //Aqui relleno el cuadro de texto con las variables resultantes de los cáculos nateriores donde se va viendo la cuenta atrás en el reloj
            txtCronoT.setText(String.format("%02d", horas)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", segundos)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", miliSegundos));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            txtCronoT.setText("Finalizado");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

sería posible me explicárais el funcionamiento del método TimePickerDialog, y si hay posibilidad de pedir los segundos y poner en 0 las horas.

También me gustaría ver las milésimas de segundos en el reloj y también fuera posible.

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues más o menos, lo he solucionado

Aquí el método que muestra la centa atrás

```
//método que recibe por parámatro un array con tres datos, horas, minutos y segundos
public void IniciarCuenta(int[] tiempo){

    //botón que inicia y parará el reloj
    btnStartOrStopT.setText("Pause");
    /botón que resetea el reloj
    btnResetT.setText("Stop");

    //aquí convierto horas y minutos a segundos y los sumo a los segundos recibidos
    segundos = tiempo[0] * 60 * 60 + tiempo[1] * 60 + tiempo[2];

    //instalaciamos el contador regresivo
    new CountDownTimer(segundos * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {

        //el método que hace actualizar el reloj con la cuenta regresiva
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            segundos = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            //cálculos para obtener horas, minutos y segundos
            int horas = segundos / (60 * 60);
            int tempMint = (segundos - (horas * 60 * 60));
            int minutos = tempMint / 60;
            segundos = tempMint - (minutos * 60);
            miliSegundos = segundos * 1000;

            //escribimos el resultado de los cálculos en TextView
            txtCronoT.setText(String.format("%02d", horas)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", segundos)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", miliSegundos));
        }

        //al finalizar la cuenta atrás
        public void onFinish() {
            //mostramos el texto Finalizado
            txtCronoT.setText("Finalizado");
            //mostramos el texto de los botones
            btnStartOrStopT.setText("Start");
            btnResetT.setText("Reset");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Método que solicita el tiempo del contador regrsivo

```
private int[] metodoSolicitarTiempo(){

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    View view = View.inflate(PaginaTemporizador.this, R.layout.time_dialog, null);
    final NumberPicker numberPickerHour = view.findViewById(R.id.numpicker_hours);
    numberPickerHour.setMaxValue(23);
    numberPickerHour.setValue(sharedPreferences.getInt("Hours", 0));
    final NumberPicker numberPickerMinutes = view.findViewById(R.id.numpicker_minutes);
    numberPickerMinutes.setMaxValue(59);
    numberPickerMinutes.setValue(sharedPreferences.getInt("Minutes", 0));
    final NumberPicker numberPickerSeconds = view.findViewById(R.id.numpicker_seconds);
    numberPickerSeconds.setMaxValue(59);
    numberPickerSeconds.setValue(sharedPreferences.getInt("Seconds", 0));
    Button cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    Button ok = view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PaginaTemporizador.this);
    builder.setView(view);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            horas = numberPickerHour.getValue();
            minutos = numberPickerMinutes.getValue();
            segundos = numberPickerSeconds.getValue();
            tiempo[0] = horas;
            tiempo[1] = minutos;
            tiempo[2] = segundos;

            txtCronoT.setText(String.format("%02d", horas)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", segundos)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", miliSegundos));

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt("Hours", numberPickerHour.getValue());
            editor.putInt("Minutes", numberPickerMinutes.getValue());
            editor.putInt("Seconds", numberPickerSeconds.getValue());
            editor.apply();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();

    return tiempo;
}
```

Y la clase getTime que gestiona el método anterior

```
class SetTime implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private EditText editText;
    private Calendar myCalendar;

    public SetTime(EditText editText, View.OnClickListener ctx){
        this.editText = editText;
        this.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        this.myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(hasFocus){
            int hour = myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            Context ctx = null;
            new TimePickerDialog(ctx, this, hour, minute, true).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.editText.setText( hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }
}
```

El layout xml que muestra el diálogo que solicita el tiempo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/teal_700"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numpicker_hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
        android:solidColor="@color/black" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numpicker_minutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
        android:solidColor="@color/black" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numpicker_seconds"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:solidColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#ffF0F0F0" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```